# MAUI: OpenAppPackageFileAsync does not want to open my files on windows 11

Tags: c#, .net, windows, xamarin, maui

I am using the the code below to read a text file that is included in my maui project. The code is part  the template project. I have set it as a maui-asset.
When I run this for Android it works, When I run it on windows it doesn't. I see the file is located in the directory (FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory).

Also I do not get any exception whatsoever. Any ideas how to solve this ?

```
        var stream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath);

        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: *"When I run it on windows it doesn't."* What **exactly** happens? exception? null stream? app hangs on some line? (if so, which line?)

Comment: nothing at all! It stay there. Even tried with try catch at place a breakpoint into the catch. Never hit. :-(

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem just the other way around, mine is working on windows but not on android.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in the asynchronous execution of the OpenPackageFileAsync. It waits on Windows until the whole code is done. On iOS/macOS it does not - it will be executed somewhat parallel. I called the method with reading files (in my case - fonts) simply as *async void createFonts*.

Solutions (alternative):

1. make the call synchronous by removing await and adding .Result at the end
2. make the call to the method containing the OpenAppPackage awaitable by returning a Task and calling with "await"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use it like

```
    public static async Task<string> ReadTextFile(string filePath)
    {
        using Stream fileStream = FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath).Result;
        using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
        return await Task.FromResult(reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result);

    }
```